# model summary has a colon symbol

Tags: r, model

I am using R through RStudio and trying to build a regression analysis model. I am looking to have it in a format where it could be written out as an equation with coefficients. I have the format of the equations below and the results. I need help constructing the final equation from the results.

I am currently trying to build a complex model with multiple variables. I am getting a model summary but I have a weird symbol between variables that I haven't encountered before, the ":" symbol.

I am basically punching in the following to create a model

```
EQ3F <- lm(CF ~ Elapsed.time*log(log(PPT+1)*P200*(FI+1)))
summary(EQ3F)
```

and I am getting the following results

[image: Model summary]

I am unsure how to interpret the coefficients from the model's summary in an equation format

Additionally, how do I interpret the results for this equation:

EQ3A <- lm(CF ~ Elapsed.time*log(log(PPT+1)*P200*(FI+1))+(PI+1)*log(PPT+1))

given the following results

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/27f1p.png)

So far from my understanding the ":" means there is an interaction, but how do I spell out this interaction in an equation format?

edited to add clarity

Comment: That is because the `*` is used as an interaction in modelling. if you want the normal multiplication, you need to use `I` function, ie `I(Elapsed.time*log(log(PPT+1)*P200*(FI+1)))`

Answer (score 1):

If you read [`?lm`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/lm.html) and go to the first paragraph of 'Details':

```
                          ... The specification 'first*second'
 indicates the _cross_ of 'first' and 'second'.  This is the same
 as 'first + second + first:second'.
```

So your use of `Elapsed.time*log(log(PPT+1)*P200*(FI+1))` is equivalent to

```
Elapsed.time +
  log(log(PPT+1)*P200*(FI+1)) +
  Elapsed.time:log(log(PPT+1)*P200*(FI+1))
```

I find the repurposing of `:` *from* sequencing *to* pairing to be a little frustrating. Similarly, I find the repurposing of `*` *from* multiplication *to* pair-expansion to also be a little frustrating. I don't have obvious/easy workarounds, so I've become accustomed to it.